# Use a state from diferent functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my question. Can i do a global state in a file and use a function to render this state that is render in other function?

Is it even possible to do something similar to this example?

```
import { useState, Fragment } from "react"

export const globalState = () => {
 const [ state, setState ] = useState<string>()
 return { state, setState }
}



const Component = () => {
 const { state } = globalState()

 return (
  <Fragment>
   <div onClick={() => setStateFunctions.setText('Hello World') }>DisplayText</div>
   <div>{state}</div>
  </Fragment>
 )
}



const setStateFunctions = {
 setText: (text: string) => {
  const { setState } = globalState()
  setState(text)
 }
}



export { Component, setStateFunctions }
```

**Note: This example throw error hook violation**

Comment: `useState` is a hook, you can call it only inside a React component or `hook`. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: Well global state in JS frameworks is a broad term. But if your end-goal is having it in the same file, why not simply make a wrapper component that holds the state, renders the children, and passes it's state to them?

Comment: Look into [RecoilJS](https://recoiljs.org/), particularly the subject of [Atoms](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/core-concepts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [React.useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext). Something like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Create a Context
const NumberContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  // Use the Provider to make a value available to all
  // children and grandchildren
  return (
    <NumberContext.Provider value={42}>
      <div>
        <Display />
      </div>
    </NumberContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Display() {
  const value = React.useContext(NumberContext);
  return <div>The answer is {value}.</div>;
}
```

Of course, you can have a `React.useState` that gets passed to the value of that provider, etc.:

```
const [numberValue, setNumberValue] = React.useState(42);

...

<NumberContext.Provider value={numberValue}>
```